# How to join a list of string skipping last 2 element

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to Join a list of string. I have a list of strings `lstItem={"a","b","c","2"}`. I am looking for a way to remove last 2 element from the list so that my expected output looks like `str1="a b"`

There is one methods I have tried

1. I used `.take()` method - `String.Join(" ", lstItem.Take(Function(x) if(x.Equals(lstItem(lstItem.Count-1)),lstItem(lstItem.Count-1,if(x.Equals(lstItem(lstItem.Count-2),lstItem.Count-2,""))))))`

Comment: Also, what about [SkipLast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skiplast?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: Just using C# code to develop workflow. Added Uipath tags so that people who used any method related this in uipath, they can reply too

Comment: Well, you should not add tags that are not relevant to your question. If your question remains the same regardless of the technology the tag relates to, it's not relevant to your question.

Comment: @John, note that `SkipLast` is supported only in .NET Core, not .NET Framework 4.8 or earlier.

Comment: @jmcilhinney That's partly why I didn't put that as an answer, since it's not clear if it's applicable to OP or not.

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Dim str = String.Join(" ", lstItem.Take(lstItem.Count - 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Linq you could do something like:

```
str1 = String.Join(" ", lstItem.Reverse().Skip(2).Reverse());
```

What this does is reverse the elements in `lstItem`, skip the first 2 (which is really the last 2), reverse again so it's back to the original order, and finally join the strings with a single space character.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach with dedicated data structure which can be used for enumerable, because iterates enumerable/collection only once.

```
Dim list = { "one","two","three","four" }

Dim result = list.Aggregate(
    (Separator:= " ", Builder:= new StringBuilder(), Items:= new List(Of Integer)()), 
    Function(composer, item)
        composer.Builder.Append(item).Append(composer.Separator)
        composer.Items.Add(item.Length + composer.Separator.Length)
        Return composer
    End Function,
    Function(composer)
        Dim lengthToCut = composer.Separator.Length + composer.Items.Take(2).Sum()
        composer.Builder.Length -= Math.Min(lengthToCut, composer.Builder.Length)
        Return  composer.Builder.ToString()
    End Function
)

result.Should().Be("one two") ' Pass Ok
```